# selectManyCheckbox update in backing bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm creating a `carousel` component, with `selectManyCheckbox` on each slide:

```
        <h:form>
            <p:carousel var="question" 
                        value="#{quizView.questions}" 
                        numVisible="1" 
                        responsive="true">
                <p:selectManyCheckbox 
                     value="#{question.options}"
                     layout="responsive"
                     columns="1">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{question.options}" 
                                   var="option" 
                                   itemLabel="#{option.text}"
                                   itemValue="#{option.text}"/>
                    <p:ajax listener="#{quizView.itemSelected}" update="@form"/>
                </p:selectManyCheckbox>
            </p:carousel>
        </h:form>
```

I would like to catch the change on the backing bean and update the property on the *option* object. Backing method is called correctly, but I don't know how to move from here:

```
public void itemSelected(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    questions = questionService.getQuestions(quizURL);
    // figure which question from event
    // figure out which option from event
    // update the property on the option
}
```

the `Option` class looks as follows:

```
public class Option {
    private Boolean correct;
    private Boolean selected;
    private String text;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

What I would like is to set the property selected to *true* if this option is selected

Comment: *"update the property on the option"* Why? JSF has already done that for you.

Comment: I've edited a question with more detail. I guess that JSF can automatically update only a boolean property? I'll try to change the `itemValue`  to `option.selected` and see if I got it right

Comment: Wait, you're using #{question.options} as both "selected values" and "available values". This makes no sense. You should use #{question.options} as "available values" and collect the "selected values" in another property.

Comment: ah, very true, thanks. This was not obvious to me, perhaps you can add it as an answer and I can accept it